# Efficient way to get the sum of absolute differences of two arrays of doubles

Tags: c

Is there a more efficient way to get the sum of absolute differences of two <s>memory blocks</s> arrays of `double` in C/C++ than to perform a loop on the array elements? So, what I wonder is if there is a function for this purpose similar to `memset`, `memcpy`, `memcmp` etc.

> How do you define the difference?

The memory blocks contain `double` values, and what I need is the sum of the absolute numerical differences between the values in the corresponding indexes of the <s>memory blocks</s> arrays.

Comment: How do you define the difference?

Comment: The memory blocks contain double values, and what I need is the sum of the absolute numerical differences between the values in the corresponding indexes of the memory blocks.

Comment: If you're talking about doubles you're not talking about "memory blocks", you're talking about arrays.

Comment: There are several x86 instructions (in SSE4.1) specifically devoted to sum-of-absolute-differences: M/PSADBW. Sadly, they operate on unsigned bytes, not doubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD).  If you use GCC you can try adding things like `-msse2 -O3` and see if it automatically generates SIMD instructions for you.  If it does, or if you choose to use a library to do explicit SIMD, you can process four floats per instruction.  To improve your chances, try to make your inner loop nice and simple so the optimizer can deal with it easily.

Comment: What you're talking about here is called *autovectorization*. It's largely a crapshoot -- it will *occasionally* work, but it only works on simple loops, is highly dependent on the compiler version, and is frequently subject to bugs. It's almost always more effective to [use compiler intrinsics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661338/sse-sse2-and-sse3-for-gnu-c).

Comment: You can try stronger flags, such as `-msse4` or `-mavx`, if the processor you'll run on is new enough.